# How to use explode in Spark / Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here is my parent Data frame .

```
+------------------+-------------------------+---------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+-----------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+-----------+
|DataPartition     |TimeStamp                |_organizationId|_sourceId|sr:Auditors                                                                                                                                                         |sr:CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate|sr:ContainsPreliminaryData|sr:ContainsRestatement|sr:CumulativeAdjustmentFactor|sr:Dcn    |sr:DocFormat|sr:DocumentId|sr:FilingDateTime        |sr:FilingDateTimeUTCOffset|sr:IsFilingDateTimeEstimated|sr:SourceTypeCode|sr:SourceTypeId|sr:StatementDate         |sr:ThirdPartySourceCode|sr:ThirdPartySourceCodeId|sr:ThirdPartySourcePriority|FFAction|!||
+------------------+-------------------------+---------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+-----------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+-----------+
|SelfSourcedPrivate|2017-11-02T10:23:59+00:00|4298009288     |80       |[WrappedArray([16165,null,UWE,3010547,3020538,true,false,true])]                                                                                                    |2017-07-31T00:00:00+00:00     |false                     |false                 |1.0                          |171105584 |ASFILED     |null         |2017-09-28T23:00:00+00:00|-300                      |false                       |10K              |3011835        |2017-07-31T00:00:00+00:00|SS                     |1000716240               |1                          |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-11-21T12:09:23+00:00|4295904170     |364      |null                                                                                                                                                                |2017-07-30T00:00:00+00:00     |false                     |false                 |1.0                          |null      |null        |null         |2017-08-08T17:00:00+00:00|-300                      |false                       |10Q              |3011836        |2017-07-30T00:00:00+00:00|SS                     |1000716240               |1                          |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-11-21T12:09:23+00:00|4295904170     |365      |[WrappedArray([3541,3024068,UNQ,3010546,null,true,true,false])]                                                                                                     |2017-09-30T00:00:00+00:00     |false                     |false                 |1.0                          |null      |null        |null         |2017-10-10T17:00:00+00:00|-300                      |false                       |10K              |3011835        |2017-09-30T00:00:00+00:00|SS                     |1000716240               |1                          |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-11-21T12:17:49+00:00|4295904170     |365      |[WrappedArray([3541,3024068,UNQ,3010546,null,true,true,false])]                                                                                                     |2017-09-30T00:00:00+00:00     |false                     |false                 |1.0                          |null      |null        |null         |2017-10-10T17:00:00+00:00|-300                      |false                       |10K              |3011835        |2017-09-30T00:00:00+00:00|SS                     |1000716240               |1                          |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-11-21T12:18:55+00:00|4295904170     |364      |null                                                                                                                                                                |2017-07-30T00:00:00+00:00     |false                     |false                 |1.0                          |null      |null        |null         |2017-08-08T17:00:00+00:00|-300                      |false                       |10Q              |3011836        |2017-07-30T00:00:00+00:00|SS                     |1000716240               |1                          |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-11-21T12:18:55+00:00|4295904170     |365      |[WrappedArray([3541,3024068,UNQ,3010546,null,true,true,false])]                                                                                                     |2017-09-30T00:00:00+00:00     |false                     |false                 |1.0                          |null      |null        |null         |2017-10-10T17:00:00+00:00|-300                      |false                       |10K              |3011835        |2017-09-30T00:00:00+00:00|SS                     |1000716240               |1                          |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-11-03T12:30:00+00:00|4295858941     |10       |null                                                                                                                                                                |2016-03-31T00:00:00+00:00     |false                     |false                 |1.0                          |null      |null        |null         |2016-04-04T12:00:00+00:00|0                         |false                       |AUTINR           |3011930        |2016-03-31T00:00:00+00:00|SS                     |1000716240               |1                          |I|!|       |
|Japan             |2017-04-25T07:34:37+00:00|4295876606     |157      |null                                                                                                                                                                |2016-09-30T00:00:00+00:00     |true                      |false                 |1.0                          |tn01037828|PDFNTV      |42149999     |2016-11-11T06:40:00+00:00|540                       |false                       |TAN              |3012925        |2016-09-30T00:00:00+00:00|SS                     |1000716240               |1                          |I|!|       |
|Japan             |2017-04-25T07:34:37+00:00|4295876606     |158      |null                                                                                                                                                                |2016-09-30T00:00:00+00:00     |false                     |false                 |1.0                          |yo00185376|PDFNTV      |42148210     |2016-11-11T06:41:00+00:00|540                       |false                       |YUH              |3013057        |2016-09-30T00:00:00+00:00|SS                     |1000716240               |1                          |I|!|       |
|Japan             |2017-04-25T07:34:37+00:00|4295876606     |159      |null                                                                                                                                                                |2016-12-31T00:00:00+00:00     |false                     |false                 |1.0                          |null      |null        |null         |2017-01-01T03:00:00+00:00|540                       |false                       |JPNINR           |3012418        |2016-12-31T00:00:00+00:00|SS                     |1000716240               |1                          |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-04-20T07:14:46+00:00|4296803503     |1        |null                                                                                                                                                                |2016-03-31T00:00:00+00:00     |false                     |false                 |1.0                          |null      |null        |null         |2016-04-04T17:00:00+00:00|-300                      |false                       |10Q              |3011836        |2016-03-31T00:00:00+00:00|SS                     |1000716240               |1                          |I|!|       |
|ThirdPartyPrivate |2017-04-19T09:49:23+00:00|4296803503     |1        |null                                                                                                                                                                |2016-03-31T00:00:00+00:00     |false                     |false                 |1.0                          |null      |null        |null         |2016-04-04T17:00:00+00:00|-300                      |false                       |10Q              |3011836        |2016-03-31T00:00:00+00:00|SS                     |1000716240               |1                          |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-05-04T09:46:05+00:00|4295907168     |446      |null                                                                                                                                                                |2016-06-30T00:00:00+00:00     |true                      |false                 |1.0                          |161773588 |ASFILED     |41178144     |2016-07-19T16:00:00+00:00|-240                      |false                       |8K0              |3011852        |2016-06-30T00:00:00+00:00|SS                     |1000716240               |1                          |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-05-04T09:46:05+00:00|4295907168     |447      |[WrappedArray([2815,3023351,UNQ,3010546,null,true,false,false])]                                                                                                    |2016-06-30T00:00:00+00:00     |false                     |false                 |1.0                          |161790278 |ASFILED     |41254569     |2016-07-28T17:00:00+00:00|-300                      |false                       |10K              |3011835        |2016-06-30T00:00:00+00:00|SS                     |1000716240               |1                          |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-05-04T09:46:05+00:00|4295907168     |450      |null                                                                                                                                                                |null                          |false                     |false                 |1.0                          |null      |null        |null         |2016-06-30T00:00:00+00:00|0                         |true                        |ESGWEB           |1002198005     |2016-06-30T00:00:00+00:00|ATD                    |null                     |null                       |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-05-04T09:46:05+00:00|4295907168     |461      |null                                                                                                                                                                |2016-06-30T00:00:00+00:00     |false                     |false                 |1.0                          |161940929 |ASFILED     |41914564     |2016-10-18T17:00:00+00:00|-300                      |false                       |14A              |3011840        |2016-06-30T00:00:00+00:00|SS                     |1000716240               |1                          |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-11-22T07:56:09+00:00|4295906830     |344      |[WrappedArray([3541,3024068,UNQ,3010546,null,true,false,false], [9574,3030421,UWE,3010547,null,true,false,false])]                                                  |2017-10-30T00:00:00+00:00     |false                     |false                 |1.0                          |null      |null        |null         |2017-11-11T17:00:00+00:00|-300                      |false                       |10K              |3011835        |2017-10-30T00:00:00+00:00|SS                     |1000716240               |1                          |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2018-01-11T10:00:22+00:00|5045881237     |15       |[WrappedArray([2719,3023331,UNQ,3010546,null,true,false,false], [5937,3026578,UWE,3010547,null,true,false,false], [8348,3029157,UNQ,3010546,null,true,false,false])]|2017-12-31T00:00:00+00:00     |false                     |false                 |1.0                          |null      |null        |null         |2018-01-01T04:00:00+00:00|480                       |false                       |MYSARS           |3012622        |2017-12-31T00:00:00+00:00|SS                     |1000716240               |1                          |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-11-22T07:56:09+00:00|4295906830     |344      |[WrappedArray([3541,3024068,UNQ,3010546,null,true,false,false], [9574,3030421,UWE,3010547,null,true,false,false])]                                                  |2017-10-30T00:00:00+00:00     |false                     |false                 |1.0                          |null      |null        |null         |2017-11-11T17:00:00+00:00|-300                      |false                       |10K              |3011835        |2017-10-30T00:00:00+00:00|SS                     |1000716240               |1                          |I|!|       |
|SelfSourcedPublic |2017-11-28T07:13:51+00:00|4295859031     |59       |null                                                                                                                                                                |2017-03-31T00:00:00+00:00     |false                     |false                 |1.0                          |null      |null        |null         |2017-04-04T12:00:00+00:00|-360                      |false                       |10Q              |null           |2017-03-31T00:00:00+00:00|SS                     |null                     |null                       |D|!|       |
+------------------+-------------------------+---------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+-----------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+-----------+
```

Out of this I want to create a data frame for sr:Auditor with four columns (DataPatition,TimeStamp,_organizationId,_sourceId)from above data frame .

How can I do this?

Here is the schema of the data frame

```
  root
 |-- _al: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _cr: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _env: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _fl: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _fs: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _fsb: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _ful: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _fun: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _ir: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _majVers: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _md: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _minVers: double (nullable = true)
 |-- _pe: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _pubStyle: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _schemaLocation: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _seg: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _sli: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _sr: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _ss: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _xsi: string (nullable = true)
 |-- env:Body: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _contentSet: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _majVers: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _minVers: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- env:ContentItem: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _action: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- env:Data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- _type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- sr:Source: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _organizationId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _sourceId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:Auditors: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:Auditor: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _auditorId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:AuditorEnumerationId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:AuditorOpinionCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:AuditorOpinionId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:AuditorOpinionOnInternalControlsId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:IsPlayingAuditorRole: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:IsPlayingCSRAuditorRole: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:IsPlayingTaxAdvisorRole: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:ContainsPreliminaryData: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:ContainsRestatement: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:CumulativeAdjustmentFactor: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:Dcn: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:DocFormat: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:DocumentId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:FilingDateTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:FilingDateTimeUTCOffset: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:IsFilingDateTimeEstimated: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:SourceTypeCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:SourceTypeId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:StatementDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:ThirdPartySourceCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:ThirdPartySourceCodeId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- sr:ThirdPartySourcePriority: long (nullable = true)
 |-- env:Header: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- env:Info: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- env:Id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- env:TimeStamp: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fun:DataPartitionId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fun:OrgId: long (nullable = true)
```

This is what I am doing

```
val dfContentEnvelope = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag", "env:ContentEnvelope").load("s3://trfsmallfffile/XML")
val dfContentItem = dfContentEnvelope.withColumn("column1", explode(dfContentEnvelope("env:Body.env:ContentItem"))).select($"env:Header.fun:DataPartitionId".as("DataPartition"),$"env:Header.env:info.env:TimeStamp".as("TimeStamp"),$"column1.*")


//val childDF=dfType.select($"_organizationId".as("organizationId"), $"_sourceId".as("sourceId"), explode($"sr:Auditors.sr:Auditor").as("Auditors"), getFFActionChild($"FFAction|!|").as("FFAction|!|"))

//childDF.show()
```

I dont know what am I missing ?

**NOTE:**
I know many questions has been asked regarding this but can somebody explain me when to use explode and why this is not working in my case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I am assuming that you are trying to explode the `Auditor` array with four columns from outer `schema` `(DataPatition,TimeStamp,_organizationId,_sourceId)`. If my assumption is correct then doing the following three steps after you get `dfContentItem` *dataframe* should solve the issue you are facing

```
val sourceDF=dfContentItem.select($"DataPartition", $"TimeStamp", $"env:Data.sr:Source.*")
val childDF = sourceDF.select($"DataPartition", $"TimeStamp", $"_organizationId", $"_sourceId", explode($"sr:Auditors.sr:Auditor").as("Auditors"))
childDF.select($"DataPartition", $"TimeStamp", $"-organizationId", $"_sourceId", $"Auditors.*").show(false)
```

**Explanation**

`DataPatition,TimeStamp` columns are already selected when you created `dfContentItem` dataframe. `_organizationId,_sourceId` columns are bound inside `"env:Data.sr:Source"`, so the first line in above solution is to separate `struct` `Source` field into separate columns which will have `_organizationId,_sourceId` fields into separate columns. The second line of code above `explodes` the `Auditor` element of `Auditors` and the final line of code is to separate the *exploded struct* to separate columns.